# Rewrite Jquery fadeIn() to use CSS3 transitions

Tags: jquery, fadein, css-transitions

Is there a way to just rewrite the JQuery fadeIn() and fadeOut() functions to use CSS3 Transitions when the browser supports it.

I'm using jquery transit for all other animations and I'm more comfortable with the fadeIn and fadeOut functions of Jquery but they don't run as well.

[Here's a link to the site I'm working on](http://layersdesignstudio.com/websites/solar)

eg;

```
if(CSS3TransitionsAvailable){

$.fn.fadeIn() = function(this, speed, callback){

//Fade this in Using CSS3 Transistions
}

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Look at Zepto. It tries to get rid all of the compatibily magic that jQuery does (meaning Zepto drops older browsers). The [fx.js](https://github.com/madrobby/zepto/blob/master/src/fx.js) module does animations with CSS

Comment: That's Pretty cool. But I need to support the older browsers as much as I dislike them :(

Answer (score 3):

If you want to replace jQuery's fadeIn and fadeOut functions with jQuery Transit, you could do something like this:

```
$.fn.fadeOut = function(speed, callback)
{
    var transitionSpeed = typeof (speed) == "undefined" ? 1000 : speed;    
    $(this).transition({opacity: 0 }, transitionSpeed, callback);

};

$.fn.fadeIn = function(speed, callback)
{
    var transitionSpeed = typeof (speed) == "undefined" ? 1000 : speed;    
    $(this).transition({opacity: 1 }, transitionSpeed, callback);

};

$("div").on("click", function () 
{
    //Fade out for 4 seconds, then fade in for 6 seconds
    $(this).fadeOut(4000, myCallBackFunction);
});

function myCallBackFunction () 
{
        $(this).fadeIn(6000);

}
```

### [JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aydbk/)

It's not perfect, but you can tweak it to your liking.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. One thing .fadeIn() does that this code does not do is begin with .show(). If you were to add the above code to a page that already uses .fadeIn(), and any elements it was applied to had been hidden with .hide(), the code would just never show those tags. You could improve this by opening your .fadeIn() with .show().css({ opacity: 0 })

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](https://github.com/louisremi/jquery.transition.js/) plugin. It might help you.

Comment: Thanks but it seems to conflict with the Jquery Transit Plugin that I'm using https://github.com/rstacruz/jquery.transit

Comment: Should it? It dosent seem to be doing that. I've used the browser inspector and it doesnt add any -webkit-transition to the elements that fade in or out. Any idea if I'm using it wrong

Comment: Oh sorry, looks like it doesn't. The plugin I suggested should work with the transit plugin. Did you try it and get any errors?

Comment: Details on how to use said plugin to accomplish said task might make this answer at least somewhat useful. Although jquery.transit is pretty much the industry standard anyway.